# How to customise ActiveAdmin TitleBar Breadcrumb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, customization, activeadmin

How do we customise Titlebar in ActiveAdmin show view?
For example, in the attached screenshot, I have breadcrumb as Admin / Orders / Order #11834 in my show view. Instead of that I want to customise it and display it as "Admin / Orders / Order# 43872378123" or "Admin / Orders / Transaction# MwlDdTc3RW".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In app/admin/order.rb

```
    show title: proc{ |order|
      order.transaction_number.present? ? "Order# #{order.order_number} & Transaction# #{order.transaction_number}" : "Order Number #{order.order_number}" } do
    end
```

In General,

```
   show title: proc {|post| post.title} do
     # ........
   end
```

Reference - https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Set-page-title

Answer (score -1):

To make a custom breadcrumb's title for model's item you can define method **display_name** in model's class (*app/models/order.rb*):

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  def display_name
    "Order number - #{id}"
  end
end
```

Tested on Rails 6.0, activeadmin [2.6.0](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/releases/tag/v2.6.0)

Comment: I created fresh Rails 6 app with activeadmin 2.6.0 and added `display_name` method to model. It changed title on detail page of this model.